# How to use Sentinel to view an already generated log file?

Tags: logging, sentinel, log-viewer

I have just started using Sentinel and I have used it to view log messages when it is running however I am curious to know if it is possible to view log messages from a log file that has already been written previously and read log in a much readable form?

I am expecting to find something like open log file from within Sentinel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com)? It can read live logs or static logs, in any format (you can describe your format in tool preferences).